# How to use SSH input mysql database?

Tags: mysql, console

I have no permission to modify `php.ini` but use `SSH`, and in phpmyadmin, I could only input a file max 2M. But now I have a big size database, so can I use SSH input the big size mysql database without modify `php.ini`?

```
put c:/mydata.sql /etc/local/mydata.sql {where is the folder I should upload?}
mysql -u myname -p
mypassword:
mysql>use mydata;
mysql>...  { what is the insert code, it may be depand the fold where I update to the server }
```

If this method still have a limit with 2M max, How should I do?

Comment: Try http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+import+dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import from file:

```
mysql --user=DB_USER --password DB_NAME < dump.sql
```

import from compressed file:

```
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | mysql --user=DB_USER --password DB_NAME
```

import from compressed file on another host (than 'localhost'):

```
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | mysql --host=your.db.server.com --user=DB_USER --password DB_NAME
```

I wouldn't specify the password on the command line, as it would get stored in bash history, just leave the `--password`-option without the actual password and mysql will prompt for it. If you don't specify this option, mysql will try to login without using a password.

To your other question, on where to upload your SQL-files: you should know, if are doing anything on a server… alternatively just use the temp-dir as suggested above or create some backup-folder outside of your webroot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access then use scp utility to copy your file to target server.I think if you don't know directory, use /tmp location.

```
scp /local/path/to/file.sql user@targetserver:/tmp
```

Enter password and file should be copied to /tmp directory on server then you can import it